# Kafka producer configuration for data ingestion

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am currently using our Kafka based data analysis pipeline to ingest huge log files from source system. During ingestion, I do not use any sort of delay/pause in producer and I just read from the log files (containing JSON) and send it to Kafka. My producer has the following configuration.

```
metric.reporters = []
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
bootstrap.servers = [1.2.3.184:9092, 1.2.3.185:9092, 1.2.3.186:9092]
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
max.block.ms = 60000
interceptor.classes = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
client.id = producer-1
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
request.timeout.ms = 30000
acks = all
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
retries = 0
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
compression.type = none
metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
buffer.memory = 33554432
timeout.ms = 30000
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
block.on.buffer.full = false
ssl.key.password = null
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
metrics.num.samples = 2
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
batch.size = 16384
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.cipher.suites = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
max.request.size = 1048576
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
linger.ms = 1
```

With this configuration, I am losing almost 1/3rd of messages with the following error

```
7:27:14.053 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR com.abc.telemetry.service.KafkaService - Batch containing 39 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for
```

I am planning to update linger.ms, batch.size for my use case. Is there anything else that I can fine tune to enable this ingestion pipeline without any data loss ?

Cheers !

Comment: Have you looked at using the Kafka Connect API? https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir supports JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen multiple questions on sending huge data over Kafka. Therefore, I would like to take a stab at this.

Kafka is not meant for sending huge payloads/messages. You should see it as a Distributed Message BUS which gives you all the privileges of a distributed system.

Kafka limits the size of the messages which could be sent across because of the following reasons

- **Huge messages increases the memory pressure in the broker.**
- **Large messages slows down the broker and handling them is very expensive.**

Solution:

- You could very well use a `Reference Based Messaging` where you send
  the location of the huge message to the consumer rather than sending
  huge data as is. This will allow you to use the capabilities of an
  external datastore and also reduces the pressure on the Kafka
  Brokers.
- You could also `chunk` the data and send it inline and `re-assemble` at the sink.

Comment: My bad that I phrased the question that way. The data is not huge. What I meant was lots of JSON data from files. When I read from the log file and forward it, I am still sending it per message.

Comment: Is there any possibility you could do producer partitioning.

Comment: You can use linger.ms combined with batch.size property.